# if P(A)$\in$P(B) which of the following is true ? 1) A$\in$B or 2) A$\subseteq$B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

So my question is this, assume for some sets A,B : ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$$\in$${\mathcal{P}(B)}$

which of the following is true?

1. $A$$\in$$B$
2. $A$$\subseteq$$B$

1. By the assumtion of ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$$\in$${\mathcal{P}(B)}$ $\implies$ ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$$\subseteq$$B$.

   Also for every set $A$$\subseteq$$A$ $\implies$ $A$$\in$${\mathcal{P}(A)}$


   if $A$$\in$${\mathcal{P}(A)}$ and ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$$\subseteq$$B$ $\implies$  $A∈P(A)$$\subseteq$$B$  $\implies$ $A$$\in$$B$
2. Counterexample:

Let $A$=$\{$1$\}$

Let $B$=$\{$$\emptyset$,$\{$1$\}$$\}$

so ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$ = $\{$$\emptyset$,$\{$1$\}$$\}$

and ${\mathcal{P}(B)}$ = $\{$$\emptyset$,$\{$$\emptyset$$\}$,$\{$$\{$1$\}$$\}$,$\{$$\emptyset$,$\{$1$\}$$\}$$\}$

so the assumption of ${\mathcal{P}(A)}$$\in$${\mathcal{P}(B)}$ holds
but $A$$\not\subseteq $$B$.

Thank you Marc van Leeuwen

Comment: that A is element of set B

Comment: That's not the transitive rule. That's the definition of $\subseteq$.

Comment: @jjagmath ty, ill update the answer. any idea about (1)  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, from the relations $x\in S\subseteq T$ it follows that $x\in T$, so from $\def\P{\mathcal P}A\in\P(A)\subseteq B$ it follows that $A\in B$, but not that $A\subseteq B$. For a counterexample to the latter, take $A=\{6\}$ (so that $\P(A)=\{\emptyset,\{6\}\}$), and $B=\{\emptyset,\{6\},\{1,3\}\}$ (the last element $\{1,3\}$ of $B$ is just for fun, to have something unrelated to $A$). Note that $A\in B$ (it is the second element listed), but $A\not\subseteq B$ since $B$ does not contain the number $6$ as element (nor indeed does it contain any number).

Comment: wow awesome answer, but is enough for (1) as a proof only by saying x∈T , so A∈P(A)⊆B it follows that A∈B ?

Comment: @Alex it is. Say it as a sentence. "$A$ is in $\mathcal P(A)$, and everything in $\mathcal P(A)$ is also in $B$ (i.e. $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq B$), so $A$ is in $B$."